# Copy file via terminal with wildcard in command like cp /path/*.dat /dist/path/

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I want to copy a file via terminal using a command like

```
cp /path/*.dat
```

As I don't know the full name of the file and I want to copy it to a certain path.

This is the command:

```
sudo cp /home/ubuntu/test/*.dat /opt/myAppFolder/License/
```

Will this command work?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is okay:

```
cp /path/to/directory/of/file/*.dat /path/to/destination
```

But note make sure it's the only file with that `.dat` extension else all such files with that extension will be copied also.

Note:

1. If already in the folder and the destination is outside that folder then the command would be **[note without the "/"]**:

   ```
   cp path/to/directory/of/file/*.dat /path/to/destination

   #or simply

   cp *.dat /path/to/destination
   ```
2. If already in the folder and both file and destination folder are in same folder location then the command would be **[note without the "/" on both source and destination]**:

   ```
   cp path/to/directory/of/file/*.dat path/to/destination

   #or simply

   cp *.dat path/to/destination
   ```

Answer (score -1):

It depends at what directory you are right now. If we are already at that directory, we do not need to include that into the path while using sudo cp command.